# Django - Autofill form data when validation error occurs in signup form

Tags: python, html, django

In my Django project, I allow a user to signup by completing a form I have created in HTML and not using Django forms . If a user makes an error, I re-render the page and pass an error through using a dictionary.

In my template I then perform an If statement checking whether there is an error, and then If so I display that error once the page has been re-rendered.

The problem I have is that if the user enters a valid email address and username, and then enters an incorrect password, then all the form data is lost when the page gets re-rendered.

What I want is that if the user enters a valid username and email, and an invalid password, vice versa, then re-render the page and also autofill the fields in the form that were valid(e.g in this case the username and email field).

Does anybody know how to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us with the relevant code snippets? You've mentioned it's a custom piece of code, it'll be hard to help without seeing what's happening in the background.

Comment: If you're not using Django Forms (you should almost certainly be using Django Forms - you can still customize the HTML), you'll need to pass the relevant POST data back to your view with the response in `form_invalid`.

Comment: @GregKaleka Ah ok, thank you for your solution.